# "or" statement in data array filtering

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I am creating a filter statement to check if the user has a certain location in their firebase node.

The array that I am using is

```
var users = [User]()
```

this is is where all my users are stored

I am filtering them by three choices: "firstLocation","secondLocation", and "thirdLocation"

I was able to successfully filter out my users array using

```
self.users = self.users.filter{(($0.firstLocation?.contains(self.passedLocation!))!)}
```

then appending it

```
self.users.append(user)
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

this essentially runs the array and filters my users of which have my passedLocation in their firstLocation firebase node. Now the problem comes when I have to run through the other two choices: "secondLocation", and "thirdLocation"

I attempted to do it by using an "or" statement like so

```
self.users = self.users.filter{(($0.firstLocation?.contains(self.passedLocation!))!)} || self.users.filter{(($0.secondLocation?.contains(self.passedLocation!))!)}
```

but I get an error of "Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type"

so what i'm asking, is there a way I can do a check of all three locations for the string passedLocation, then filtering my users if one of those checks comes up as a match

Comment: The `filter` method returns an array of objects, NOT a Boolean type. So you can't use `||` statement.

Comment: Have you tried NSSortDescriptor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want one filter with the "or" inside that one filter.

```
self.users = self.users.filter{(($0.firstLocation?.contains(self.passedLocation!))!) || (($0.secondLocation?.contains(self.passedLocation!))!)}
```